# How to build a tar archive using gradle on Windows without file owner information?

Tags: gradle, tar

I'm trying to build a **tar archive** from my project with gradle on **Windows**.

```
task buildTarball(dependsOn: filterResources, type: Tar) {
    from "${project.buildDir}/resources"
    destinationDir project.buildDir
    archiveName = project.ext.internetTarballName
    compression = Compression.GZIP
}
```

This works well, except that there are errors when unpacking the archive on an **unix machine** over an existing directory:

```
tar: config: Cannot utime: Permission denied
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

`config` is a directory inside the tarball. Invoking the unpack command with `--no-overwrite-dir` works.

Gradle uses my **Windows user name** as the owner of all files and directories in the generated archive. I suspect this is the cause of the error. How can I remove the owner information out of the tarball with gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root problem was not gradle, but the target environment. The `config` directory is owned by root, which forbids `tar` to overwrite creation, modification and access timestamps.

The message posted in the question above is not an error, though. Tar continues to unpack objects after this message. That message can be easily avoided by appending the `--no-overwrite-dir` switch to the `tar -x` command.